# Difference between Linux and Windows linker

Tags: windows, linux, gcc, linker, shared-libraries

What is the difference in linking on various operating system?

For example the following code produces a linker error on Windows (compiled both with Vs2010 and gcc), but compiles successfully on Linux (Ubuntu,gcc):

```
extern int foo

int main() {
    foo=1;
}
```

Gcc command:

```
gcc -shared filename.cpp
```

Comment: Do you compile the code on Windows as a shared library too?

Comment: Yes, under vs with 'dll' insted of 'exe'; the gcc command was the same

Comment: I know almost nothing about gcc, but is it really linking at that stage?  The documentation for -shared says it produces an object that can then be linked with other objects at a later stage; e.g. you are not linking a final executable.  This seems more akin to building a static library on Windows, which in this case will not give you any compiler or linker errors.

Comment: What is the linker error message?

Comment: I'm pretty sure your example yields a compile error on all standard complaint C compilers because you're missing a `;` on the first line.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to compile it as a windows shared library you need something like (code stolen from Wikipedia!) :-

```
#include <windows.h>


// DLL entry function (called on load, unload, ...)
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HANDLE hModule, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    return TRUE;
}

// Exported function - adds two numbers
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) double AddNumbers(double a, double b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

Windows shared modules (DLLs) require a DllMain entry point (executed the first time the module is loaded) and function names need to be exported via the declspec gobledygook before they can be used by another program.

Comment: I must disagree with wikipedia :-) I don't think DLLMain is required for compilation/linking; if I erase the keyword `extern` the rest of the code is compiled and linked successfully witouh the `DllMain` function. To use the dll, I must have the `extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)`, but that is after linking :-)

Comment: You could be right! Last time I coded up a DLL many years ago I need to do some initialisation so I always coded up the DllMain and sort of assumed you had to.

Comment: runtime often provides the DllMain

Comment: You don't need the `extern "C"` unless you want to force C linkage. C++ signatures work just fine in a dll too.